# Doesn't PHP curl_getinfo work for remote URLs from wordpress blogs or sites that use wordpress for content management?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, imageurl

I am using PHP to find whether image urls are active or broken. I have been using the following code which I found in one of the answers on stackoverflow itself.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); 

curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 200)
{ 
    echo "image exists<br/>";
}

curl_close($ch);
```

If I use a normal image URL then the program is working fine, but if the image link is present in a blog like this (http://unspokenstyle.files.wordpress.com/2009/01/yorkegrammy.jpg) or if the content management is done using wordpress like this (http://rockandroll.blog.br/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/radiohead-na-rollingstone3.jpg), then I am getting a "400 Bad Request" error.

Am I missing something in the code?

Please help.

P.S.: I cannot use certain PHP functions like PHP getimagesize as I am using third party hosting. So I have to use CUrl.

Comment: sorry to ask the obvious question, but are u sure the image actually does exist?

Comment: yeah...the links I mentioned in the question are working urls, but they give the 400 Bad Request error

Comment: does it work without the NOBODY flag?

Comment: the problem exists without the NOBODY flag as well :(

Comment: sorry, but still getting the errors

Comment: I have edited the question to add the urls not working

Comment: 12y later i am having same issue with curl inside wordpress and nobody got any solution :(

Answer (score 0):

I tested your function and on my rig it's working just fine. So it's not your code. Is it possible they blocked your IP? Does the function work when you fetch a image from your own server (with http://)?

On your host can you use the PHP function: file_get_contents($url)?

Comment: the function file_get_contents($url) is not working on the server..may be some security thing.

Comment: Have you tried fetching an image on your own server? `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myserver.tld/image.jpg");`

Comment: yes..if the image is on my server, then the output is "image exists"